# ActionBar is overlapping first CardView in RecyclerView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

The first item (CardView) in my RecyclerView (contained in a RelativeLayout) is overlapped by the top action bar, how do I get fix this problem?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.goaandroidlessonslistmockup.MainActivity">

    <!--Base RecyclerView-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your RelativeLayout:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Your issue is that your `RelativeLayout` is displayed underneath the actionbar. There are other solutions, but without seeing your layouts I can't be more specific.